# Using redux-form reducer.plugin() with dynamically generated form names

Tags: redux-form

A lot of the forms I use within my app are generated dynamically so in the plugin reducer I do not know the name of the form before it is created but would like to use the benefits of the reducer plugin.

In the case below it works fine if I know my form is called foo but in my app I have multiple forms dynamically named such as CalcForm1, CalcForm2 .... CalcFormN etc. which all require the functionality of the "CALCULATE" action.type

Is there a why I can use this with dynamically named forms.

Many thanks

```
export const formPlugin = {
  foo: (state = {}, action) => { // <----- 'foo' is name of form given to     reduxForm()
    switch (action.type) {
      case "CALCULATE":
        return {
          ...state,
          values: doCalculate(action.payload.expressions, state.values)
        };

      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write wrap function and use `action.meta.form`

something like

```
const formHack = (state, action) => {
   return (action.meta && action.meta.form) ? 
       formReducer.plugin({
         [action.meta.form]: {...}
       })(state, action) : formReducer(state, action)
}
```